# Deleting a mailchimp campaign - Resource not found

Tags: php, curl, mailchimp

I am trying to delete a mailchimp campaign, but getting an error. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my curl command:

```
public function executeCurlDelete($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'apikey:'.$this->apikey);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);//returns output as variable

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    $output = CJSON::decode(curl_exec($ch));
    curl_close($ch);
    if ($output !== true){
        throw new CException($output['title']);
    }

    return $output === true;
}

public function deleteCampaign($campaignId){
    ///campaigns/{campaign_id}
    $url = "$this->apiEndpoint/campaigns/$campaignId";
    return $this->executeCurlDelete($url);
}
```

Here is the error:

The requested resource could not be found.

Comment: i guess that second fetch is a mistake, you probably mean `$output = CJSON::decode($result);` , not `$output = CJSON::decode(curl_exec($ch));`

Comment: Thanks - I think you are correct